# Automating cmake to .vcxproj file generation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio Solution (.sln). And I have some C++ projects (.vcxproj) which are generated by `cmake.exe`. As my project is targeting to multiple platforms, the project source file is cmakelists.txt.

And, I have C# projects (.csproj) in my .sln file. So I cannot use [Visual Studio 2019 CMake Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) type.

For now, I do these procedure before opening my .sln file:

1. Run `cmake -G ...` command to generate .vcxproj files. I manually skip if cmakelists.txt is not changed.
2. Open .sln file.

This is cumbersome. If somebody in my team changes cmakelists.txt and commit to our source repository, I don't know whether the cmakelists.txt is changed and recklessly run `cmake -G ...` command before opening .sln file.

Is there any better way to automate this cumbersome process? I looked for how to run custom action on opening (or loading) .sln file in Visual Studio, but I cannot find the exact one.

Comment: When building a CMake-generated project in Visual Studio, Visual Studio will first check to see if CMake needs to be re-run first (by checking if any CMake files have changed). If needed, CMake will re-run from with the VS solution, and the project files will be updated accordingly. You shouldn't need to run CMake manually, nor should you need to continually open/close your VS solution. The solution will simply reload if CMake updates any of the project files...

Comment: Thank you! How can I generate the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: You only need to run `cmake -G ...` once to generate the initial VS solution (and accompanying project files). After running for the first time, you can open VS and CMake will simply re-run (if necessary) from within Visual Studio.

Comment: I did `cmake -G` then opened the generated .sln file then added xx.c file in cmakelists.txt then reopend the .sln file, but xx.c does not exist in the generated project files. What am I missing? @squareskittles

Comment: There is no need to ever close the VS solution file. Just leave it open; even better, install the CMake extension for Visual Studio and edit the CMakeLists.txt files in Visual Studio. The Visual Studio solution will not update until you run a build, so Navigate to *Build > Build Solution* and CMake will re-run within Visual Studio, and you will be prompted to load the fresh solution.